# why is "getWidth()" returning 0 for me?

Tags: java

I'm asking this because I'd like to know why it is - as opposed to what I ought to do to circumvent the problem.  I really just want a technical explanation of why getWidth() in the math-operation (assigned to currentXMargin) isn't returning a value.  I GLabel'd testValue1 and testValue2; testValue1 obviously returns the correct pixel amount, whereas testValue2 returns -210 (half the pyramid based of course); it needs to say 167 (as it does for testValue1 where I hard-code the formula in).  What's more, when I try to use currentXMargin in the GRect constructor, it also fails to work there, returning the same resuts (-210 if I use the variable, and the correct amount if I just hard-code the formula in), and the pyramid base is halfway off screen to the left.

So why isn't getWidth returning a value to the operation in the currentXMargin assignment (below the run method)?

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

/** Width of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

/** Height of each brick in pixels */
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

/** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;


public void run() {

    double testValue1 = (getWidth() - (BRICKS_IN_BASE * BRICK_WIDTH))/2;;
    GLabel test = new GLabel("width: "+testValue1,0,10);
    add(test);

    double testValue2 = currentXMargin;
    GLabel test2 = new GLabel("width: "+testValue2,0,20);
    add(test2);

    //doRow();

}//run

    private int brickCount = BRICKS_IN_BASE;
    private double currentXMargin = (getWidth() - (BRICKS_IN_BASE *     BRICK_WIDTH))/2;
    private double currentYMargin;
    GRect brick[] = new GRect[14];

    private void doRow(){
        for(int i=0;i<brickCount;i++){
            brick[i] = new GRect(currentXMargin,10,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT);
            add(brick[i]);
            currentXMargin += BRICK_WIDTH;
        }
        currentYMargin -= BRICK_HEIGHT;
        brickCount -= 1;
    }//doRow


}//class
```

Comment: The likely reason is the component hasn't been realised or laid out yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` is the default value for numeric types until they get initialized. You call `getWidth()` during initialization of your instance fields, i.e. at a time when the width simply has not been initialized yet.

Comment: So I should initialize the instance field (that calls getWidth) within the run method?

Comment: Yes, read up on "lazy initialization". Essentially you would initialize the value right before you really need it for the first time.